# How do I make a program that separates dictionaries and has exception handling in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, exception

How do I make a program that separates a dictionary such as in the format as: `{"one":2, 3:4, "five":6, 7:8}` into:

```
one: 2
3: 4
five: 6
7: 8
```

Each pair or key, value in a new line, with exception handling that can detect if a dictionary is empty or not a valid input.

I have thought about using loops but I'm not sure if that's necessary or even works.

Comment: What would make the _dictionary_ "not a valid input"?

Comment: Oh sorry, I just updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest is a plain ol' loop:

```
d = {"one":2, 3:4, "five":6, 7:8}
for k, v in d.items():
  print(k, v, sep=": ")
```

You could also format the pairs in a list comprehension if that suits you better, but it's arguably less readable:

```
print(*[f"{k}: {v}" for (k, v) in d.items()], sep="\n")
```

Comment: Ah thank you! But Im still not quite sure how to do the exception handling

Comment: What exception handling do you need? If you want to print something if the dict is empty, wrap things in an `if d: ... else: print("Nothing in the dict")`